Infer Generic Type 2nd param based on 1st param (const/type list of T<A,B>, Generic Type that maps A to B)
I have implementations of an abstract class (event processor), providing two generic parameters - an enum value (event name) and a type (event payload):
enum EventNames {
  EVENT_NAME_1='event_name_1',
  EVENT_NAME_2='event_name_2',
  EVENT_NAME_3='event_name_3',
  EVENT_NAME_4='event_name_4',
}

type Event1Payload = {
  somePayload1: string
}

type Event2Payload = {
  somePayload2: string
}

abstract class EventProcessor<TEventName extends EventNames, TEventPayload> {
  abstract process(payload: TEventPayload): void;
}


I would like to have a function that accepts an enum value and a type, and validates the type based on the enum - the type should be matching the 2nd generic type of the class that has that enum value.

The function is:
function publish<TEventName extends EventNames>(EventName: TEventName, payload: GetPayloadTypeForEventName<TEventName>): void {
  // ...
}

So assuming having 2 implementations of:
class Event1Processor extends EventProcessor<EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1, Event1Payload> {
  process(payload: Event1Payload): void {
 // ...
 }
}

class Event2Processor extends EventProcessor<EventNames.EVENT_NAME_2, Event2Payload> {
  process(payload: Event2Payload): void {
 // ...
 }
}

When calling an event name without the matching payload type it will have a typescript error, for example:
publish(EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1, {});

should not work, and calling with the matching Event1Payload type should work:
publish(EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1, {
  somePayload1: 'some string'
});


So there should be at least a type/const that contains the implementations to fetch the types from:
const eventProcessors = [Event1Processor, Event2Processor] as const

or
type eventProcessors = Event1Processor | Event2Processor

however I don't know how to create the type that infers from it the enum value->payload mapping.
I can create types that fetch the generics from types:
type getTypeOfFirstGenericParameter<T> = T extends EventProcessor<infer U, any> ? U : never
type getTypeOfSecondGenericParameter<T> = T extends EventProcessor<any, infer U> ? U : never

and I tried infering the types from the const array however I get Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite:
type GetPayloadTypeForEventName<N extends JobAction<any>[], Acc extends string[] = []> =
  N['length'] extends Acc['length'] ?
    Acc :
    GetPayloadTypeForEventName<N, [...Acc, getTypeOfFirstGenericParameter<N[Acc['length']]>]>;



I am trying to be able to get a generatedEventNamesType type from the eventProcessors type/const array:

const eventProcessors = [Event1Processor, Event2Processor] as const

or
type eventProcessors = Event1Processor | Event2Processor

A type that maps the array/"or" of the types and fetching their 1st generic argument, creating a new type out of it with an "or" relation between the possible types, as follows:
type GetEventNamesFromEventProcessors<TEventProcessor[]> = ...

// Type:
GetEventNamesFromEventProcessors<eventProcessors>
// Should be equivalent to:
type generatedEventNamesType = JobTypes.EVENT_NAME_2 | EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1;


Hmm, I really wish your code here were a [mre] I could just copy and paste instead of having to extract code from prose around it. Right now your EventProcessor class is invalid since the method isn't abstract, and EventTypes and JobTypes are typos?  And the class doesn't use its first type parameter, which is not recommended. If EventProcessor doesn't depend structurally on a type parameter, it shouldn't use the type parameter. Please [edit] to fix these.

(see prev comment). Your unused type parameter makes me think that you're going about encoding the relationship between event name and payload in a roundabout and ineffective way. You should just write a direct type mapping interface from key to value as shown in this playground link, and then everything just works, where you only need one type parameter (for the event name) and you can just look up the payload directly. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thanks. Indeed they are typos I fixed them now.
I am trying to be able to infer with the least added code, so I thought each event processor could declare the event name and payload type it handles, and having a list of event processors will allow me to automatically map it, however your point is valid and I consider the best way might be what you suggested afterwards,
eventhough I initialy thought to avoid a central mapping place so each event processor will declare its own event name/payload. I will play with your suggested solution tomorrow and will update, Thank you so much!

@jcalz Thanks thats indeed what I looked for, I wasn't aware of implementing it this way. It addresses the question :)

If you want to infer one type argument from another, then you probably only actually to accept one type argument and not two.  Somewhere in your code you need to tell TypeScript which EventNames member goes with which payload. It kind of looks like you were trying to distribute that information across the subclasses of EventProcessor. But since your EventProcessor<K, T> had no structural dependence on K (that is, it had no member that had anything to do with K whatsoever), a subclass like EventProcessor<K1, T> can't really be told apart from EventProcessor<K2, T>, and thus attempts at inference are quite likely to fail. See The TypeScript FAQ: Why doesn't type inference work on this interface: interface Foo<T> { }?
The easiest approach here is to just make a mapping interface that connects the EventNames to the payloads explicitly and in a single place:
interface EventPayloadMapping {
  [EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1]: Event1Payload
  [EventNames.EVENT_NAME_2]: Event2Payload
  // presumably others
}

Once you have that, you can rewrite all the rest of your code to be generic in just K extends keyof EventPayloadMapping (or K extends EventNames if you actually have payload types for all events). If you want to refer to the event name, that's K. If you want to refer to the payload type, you can look it up by indexing into EventPayloadMapping: that's EventPayloadMapping[K].
So your other code becomes:
abstract class EventProcessor<K extends keyof EventPayloadMapping> {
  abstract process(payload: EventPayloadMapping[K]): void;
}

class Event1Processor extends EventProcessor<EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1> {
  process(payload: Event1Payload): void {
    // ...
  }
}

class Event2Processor extends EventProcessor<EventNames.EVENT_NAME_2> {
  process(payload: Event2Payload): void {
    // ...
  }
}

function publish<K extends keyof EventPayloadMapping>(
  EventName: K, payload: EventPayloadMapping[K]
): void {
  // ...
}

You can see that instead of two generic type parameters, you've only ever got a single one.  And now it behaves as you want:
publish(EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1, {}); // error!

publish(EventNames.EVENT_NAME_1, {
  somePayload1: 'some string'
}); // okay

Playground link to code
